Is there a way to change the OSB error in Oracle Fusion Middleware to a custom error
I'm trying to change the error provided by Oracle in webservices to a custom error for example:
From this 
to something like this: 
Is there a way to validate on Tags in request?
I tried adding error handler in the pipeline and create a new fault xsl file that checks on input parameters but it works only if I removed mandatory field
